# Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed. I cant spot the error

Tags: asp.net

This line is getting the error message how do i fix it?

```
    <asp:TextBox id="txtInventory" runat="server" onfocus=HighlightGridRow() 
BorderStyle=None ReadOnly=True CssClass="SolRegText" STYLE=width:115;" 
tabIndex="-1" Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,InventoryIDColumnName) %>">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What error message?

Comment: `onfocus=HighlightGridRow()` => `onfocus="HighlightGridRow()"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quote strings to close the attribute values.

```
 <asp:TextBox id="txtInventory" runat="server" onfocus="HighlightGridRow()" BorderStyle="None" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="SolRegText" STYLE="width:115;" tabIndex="-1" Text="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,InventoryIDColumnName) %>"></asp:TextBox>
```